# Trying to retrieve a list of possible youtube videos based on keywords with Jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net, json, youtube, jsonp

Please help! please.

I am trying to have a user enter in a "keyword" into a search box and I'm trying to have a list of possible Youtube movies return from Youtube (ONLY TITLES) so I can bind them to an auto-complete feature of my textbox:

I am trying to use this code in order to do so:

http://jsfiddle.net/0hnwf414/

```
     $(document).ready(function () {
$("#show").click(function () {
    getYoutube($("#Search").val());
});
  });

   function getYoutube(title) {
        $.ajax({
          type: "GET",
           url: yt_url = 'http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?q=' + title + '&format=5&max-results=1&v=2&alt=jsonc',
    dataType: "jsonp",
    success: function (response) {
        if (response.data.items) {
            $.each(response.data.items, function (i, data) {
                var video_id = data.id;
                var video_title = data.title;
                var video_viewCount = data.viewCount;

                var video_frame = "<iframe width='600' height='385' src='http://www.youtube.com/embed/" + video_id + "' frameborder='0' type='text/html'></iframe>";

                var final1 = "<div id='title'>" + video_title + "</div><div>" + video_frame + "            </div><div id='count'>" + video_viewCount + " Views</div>";
                   $("#result").html(final1);
             });
            } else {
                $("#result").html("<div id='no'>No Video</div>");
            }
        }
    });
         }


      <input type="text" id="Search" />
      <br/>
       <input id="show" type="button" value="Submit" />
         <div id="result"></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are rendering videoframe and that's what cause it to render the frame of youtube inside the list. remove it like following and it should work.

```
var final1 = "<div id='title'>" + video_title + "</div><div id='count'>" + video_viewCount + " Views</div>";
               $("#result").html(final1);
```